# How can I get a reference to the Scene object in React Three Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the `scene` object programatically in React Three Fiber, so that I can add a Three component in the traditional way: `scene.add(myThing)`. I've tried using `const canvasRef = useRef()` with `<Canvas ref={canvasRef} />` but the ref seems to be undefined when passing to another Component.

I know this is probably really bad practice, but what I'm trying to do, is [convert this](https://codepen.io/navin_moorthy/pen/qBWYORJ) for use in React Three Fiber, but `Geometry` has been replaced with `BufferGeometry` and I'm a bit lost. [I found this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-geometry-vertices-is-undefined/3133), but as mentioned, I'm just trying to use `scene.add()` for now until I can figure more out about the inner workings of Three.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `useThree` provided by React Three Fiber.

https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in one of my project and i went for this using Three.js and three fiber :

```
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber"
import { BoxGeometry, Mesh, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";

  const { scene } = useThree()

  const addThreeComponent = () => {
    const geometry = new BoxGeometry(100, 10, 100);
    const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const newBox = new Mesh(geometry, material);
    newBox.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    scene.add(newBox);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up implementing `forwardRef` myself.

```
const ThreeForwardRef = forwardRef(props, ref) => {
   const { scene, camera } = useThree();
   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      scene,
      camera,
   }), [scene, camera]);
}

export const MyCanvas = forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
   return (
      <Canvas>
         <ThreeForwardRef ref={ref} />
         { children }
      </Canvas>
   );
}
```

Usage:

```
const ref = useRef();
// ref.current.scene;

<MyCanvas ref={ref}>
   ...
<MyCanvas />
```